# Scraping with Nokogiri and Ruby before and after JavaScript changes the value

Tags: javascript, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have a program that scrapes value from  https://web.apps.markit.com/WMXAXLP?YYY2220_zJkhPN/sWPxwhzYw8K4DcqW07HfIQykbYMaXf8fTzWT6WKnuivTcM0W584u1QRwj

My current code is:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(source_url))

puts doc.css('span.indexDate').text
date = doc.css('span.indexDate').text
date = Date.parse(date)
puts date
values = doc.css('table#CdsIndexTable td.col2 span')
puts values
```

This scrapes the date and values of the second column from the "CDS Indexes" table correctly which is fine. Now, I want to scrape the similar values from the "Bond Indexes" table where I am facing the problem.

I can see a JavaScript function changes it without loading the page and without changing the URL of the page. The difference between these two tables is their IDs are different which is exactly that it should be. But, unfortunately when I try with:

```
values = doc.css('table#BondIndexTable')
puts values
```

I get nothing from the Bond Indexes table. But I get values from CDS Indexes table if I use:

```
values = doc.css('table#CdsIndexTable')
puts values
```

How can I get the values from both tables?

Comment: Does Nokogiri execute javascript? If it does, and those "javascript functions" use ajax maybe cross-domain policy is blocking them from completing? Have you tried something like PhantomJS?

Comment: Nokogiri does NOT run JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use PhantomJS you can also use the network sniffer on Firefox or Chrome development tools, and you will see that the HTML table data is returned with a javascript POST request to the server.

Then instead of opening the original page URL with Nokogiri, you'd instead run this POST from your Ruby script and parse and interpret that data instead. It looks like it's just JSON data with HTML embedded into it. You could extract the HTML and feed that to Nokogiri.

It requires a bit of extra detective work, but I've used this method many times with JavaScript web pages and scraping. It works OK for most simple tasks, but it requires a bit of digging into the inner workings of the page and network traffic.

Here's an example of the JSON data from the Javascript POST request:

*Bonds*:
https://web.apps.markit.com/AppsApi/GetIndexData?indexOrBond=bond&ClientCode=WSJ

*CDS*:
https://web.apps.markit.com/AppsApi/GetIndexData?indexOrBond=cds&ClientCode=WSJ

Here's the quick and dirty solution just so you get an idea. This will grab the cookie from the initial page and use it in the request to get the JSON data, then parse the JSON data and feed the extracted HTML to Nokogiri:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

# Open the initial page to grab the cookie from it
p1 = open('https://web.apps.markit.com/WMXAXLP?YYY2220_zJkhPN/sWPxwhzYw8K4DcqW07HfIQykbYMaXf8fTzWT6WKnuivTcM0W584u1QRwj')

# Save the cookie
cookie = p1.meta['set-cookie'].split('; ',2)[0]

# Open the JSON data page using our cookie we just obtained
p2 = open('https://web.apps.markit.com/AppsApi/GetIndexData?indexOrBond=bond&ClientCode=WSJ',
          'Cookie' => cookie)

# Get the raw JSON
json = p2.read

# Parse it
data = JSON.parse(json)

# Feed the html portion to Nokogiri
doc = Nokogiri.parse(data['html'])

# Extract the values
values = doc.css('td.col2 span')
puts values.map(&:text).inspect

=> ["0.02%", "0.02%", "n.a.", "-0.03%", "0.02%", "0.04%", 
    "0.01%", "0.02%", "0.08%", "-0.01%", "0.03%", "0.01%", "0.05%", "0.04%"]
```

Comment: @K.M.RakibulIslam Ok. Looks like it's not quite so simple. You probably need the cookies from the original web page embedded in the request headers. That's a bit beyond the scope of a simple answer, so maybe you want to try PhantomJS instead. I got the links using the Network panel in Chrome Developer Tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network . Just press the links on the live web page and watch what network calls are being made by the javascript using the developer tools.

Comment: The [mechanize gem](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) can simplify this, because it handles the cookie for you, and also gives you access to a parsed Nokogiri doc.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Capybara with the Poltergeist driver to execute the Javascript and format the page. Poltergeist is a wrapper for the PhantomJS headless browser.  Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.run_server = false

module GetPrice
  class WebScraper
    include Capybara::DSL

    def get_page_data(url)
      visit(url)
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page.html)
      doc.css('td.col2 span')
    end
  end
end

scraper = GetPrice::WebScraper.new
puts scraper.get_page_data('https://web.apps.markit.com/WMXAXLP?YYY2220_zJkhPN/sWPxwhzYw8K4DcqW07HfIQykbYMaXf8fTzWT6WKnuivTcM0W584u1QRwj').map(&:text).inspect
```

Visit here for a complete example using Amazon.com:
https://github.com/wakproductions/amazon_get_price/blob/master/getprice.rb

Answer (score 1):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is a headless browser with a JavaScript API. Since you need to run the scripts on the page you are scraping, a browser will do that for you; and PhantomJS will allow you to manipulate and scrape the page after the script execution.