# Nokogiri only returning 5 results

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I want Nokogiri to return all the `div`s with the following class: `styled__PostItemWrapper-sc-e4ns84-7`

however on my webpage, I can see so many `div`s with this class, here is a sample:

[image]

yet when I do this:

```
Nokogiri.HTML(res.body).css('div.styled__PostItemWrapper-sc-e4ns84-7').size
```

I only get 5 results

Why is that?

I was expecting all of the `div`s with that class but I only got the first 5

Comment: Perhaps those divs are not included in the original HTML loaded from the server but added by JavaScript after loading?

Comment: If I look at the body of the html response, i can see the text that belongs to those divs

Comment: I just disabled JS on the browser and it is what you said. Thank you for that. However now that I know this, how do i parse the content loaded via JS?

Comment: Hello Adam, your situation has changed, please edit the title and the content of your question.

Comment: @AdamAfzal you are going to need to use `nokogiri` in conjunction with a browser/js aware library like `watir` or `capybara`. This will allow you to visit the page, wait for the information to load, and then pass the loaded page through to nokogiri for parsing. This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364309/scraping-with-nokogiri-and-ruby-before-and-after-javascript-changes-the-value) provides a very simple example.

Comment: Without the actual site and a [mcve] of your code, there's no real way to help.